# Java client-server chat protocol design

Tags: java, client-server

I need to create a protocol for client-server chat on Java.
I use xml to encode messages between them, but I can't decide how to return decoded data to server.

First time, i created many object `implements IAction` (e.g. `Auth` object represents a packet, about new user in chat) which vary depending on their content.
So, when server receives a socket, it calls my `public IAction decode(String s)` and then, server should determine what object it is:

```
if (myIAction instanceof Auth) {
   server.doMagicAuth((Auth) myIAction);
}
```

but it was looking ugly to me coz of typecasting and many ifes

Another approach was to create one common object, called `Packet`, that can contain `intValue`, `floatValue`, `stringValue` etc. And also it had a flag, that talked about what kind of packet it is.
But it was the worst idea coz of collisions. For example, how to send 2 int values it this packet? e.g. password and users_id?

And the latest idea was to observe server.
Server should have many overloaded `public void action(IAction a)` methods (`action(Auth a)` ... etc), and protocol should notify a server depending on what kind of packet it is.

And i cant decide, what method to use. Maybe you have some completely different ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chat client-server application usually does not send/receive 2 ints or 3 floats or anything like that but just strings.
These days I would probably either send JSON objects serialized as strings or just plain strings.

If using XML is a firm requirement you need to define some XML format 
(possibly through some XSD even though that's not mandatory in your case) 
and stick to that format. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<message text="Hello"/>
```

When this is sent from any client, you take it on the server side, 
get the `text` value and send it from the server to all connected clients. 
That is all they want from you, I believe.

Comment: XML is a limitation of my lab =(
And the question was in another: how to pass decoded data to server from protocol

Comment: That decoded data is nothing but a string. Just send it to your server any way you like. Calling a method, sending an event, almost anything would work here.

Comment: and again, i don't ask how to represent my data in packets) it's protocol's job. I can't decide how to present decoded data to server. e.g. `Protocol` decodes an xml string and understands that it's an packet, with a new message from `user123` to `user21`, so i need to ask server to send a message to `user21`. And a question "how to ask server to do it?" is actually what i wanted to know)

Comment: Well, if your message is already decoded and contains `sender`, `receiver`, `message` just post it to some queue. The server reads that queue (say on each N seconds) and sends those messages out. Represent it by a class with these 3 fields then.

Comment: Or you can immediately call a method on the server and the server will dispatch it immediately to the receiver. But in any case this above sounds like the most natural representation.

Comment: Yes, if you want to demonstrate that knowledge by using some design pattern :). You can use it, sounds applicable here.